# how to pass sql command "Select * from table_name" in shell variable

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to print the sql statement using shell variable but not getting expected output :

```
pdate=`date +%d-%b-%Y`
query='"select \* from table_name where partition_date='"$pdate"' and \$CONDITIONS"'
echo $query
```

Expected Output :

```
"select * from table_name where partition_date="30-Nov-2018" and \$CONDITIONS"
```

Actual Output :

```
"select \* from table_name where partition_date=30-Nov-2018 and \$CONDITIONS"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape anything inside single quotes: nothing has special meaning in there: remove the backslash from the asterisk.

Comment: Also, always quote your variables: `echo "$query"` -- I suspect this error lead to you thinking you needed to escape the asterisk in the first place.

Comment: @glennjackman if escape character is removed then `echo $query` will expend asterik.

Comment: See my 2nd comment.

Comment: if I remove escape before asterisk it is printing all file names which are present at respective path

Comment: @glennjackman you solved the first problem thanks but I also need date to be in double quotes now my output is :                                                                                                             "select * from table_name where partition_date=30-Nov-2018 and \$CONDITIONS"

Comment: Then you need to put literal double quotes inside the single quotes: `...partition_date="'"$pdate"'"...`

Comment: Do you want the double quotes as the first/last chars in the result string? I think you do not, but I don't know how you're using the variable. Double quotes do not nest, so you're going to run into trouble: I think you should remove them.

Comment: you got it ... thanks issue Solved Final Answer is                      query='"select * from table_name where partition_date="'"$pdate"'" and \$CONDITIONS"' Thanks @glennjackman :)

Answer (score 5):

To get your desired output:

```
pdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y)
query='"select * from table_name where partition_date="'"$pdate"'" and \$CONDITIONS"'
# ............^^ no backslash ........................^..........^ quotes as plain chars
echo "$query"
```

Another approach with bash is `printf`: that allows you to simplify the quoting

```
printf -v query '"select * from table_name where partition_date="%s" and \$CONDITIONS"' "$pdate"
```